# How to use AdSense on an AJAX based site the right way?

Tags: html, ajax

I am currently finishing my web application which will be a soccer/sports data related dashboard. The URL won‘t change whenever a user clicks on a different team in the sidebar to fetch the according data from an API via AJAX.

I would like to implement a Google AdSense skyscraper which refreshes on a user click within the sidebar (so basically the same dashboard and URL, but new data, each click on a team in the sidebar = new AJAX data = new impression?). So the event to refresh the AdSense banner  would be the user interaction and not an autorefresh.

Would that be in the terms of AdSense and a proper way to implement it into my web application?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the prescribed way.  The AdSense API has a refresh method you can call.

I would also recommend setting some sort of throttle on this so that if the user is constantly clicking around on different content, that you're not refreshing that ad too quickly.